# How to add second y axis to seqfplot with sequence frequency?

Tags: r, plot, traminer

I'm working with TraMineR to do a sequence analysis of educational data. I can get R to produce a plot of the 10 most frequent sequences in the data using code similar to the following:

```
library(TraMineR)

##Loading the data
data(actcal)

##Creating the labels and defining the sequence object
actcal.lab <- c("> 37 hours", "19-36 hours", "1-18 hours", "no work")
actcal.seq <- seqdef(actcal, 13:24, labels=actcal.lab)

## 10 most frequent sequences in the data
actcal.freq <- seqtab(actcal.seq)
actcal.freq

## Plotting the object
seqfplot(actcal.seq, pbarw=FALSE, yaxis="pct", tlim=10:1, cex.legend=.75, withlegend="right")
```

However, I'd also like to have the frequencies of each sequence (which are in the object actcal.freq) along the right side of the plot. For example, the first sequence in the plot created by the code above represents 37.9% of the data (as the plot currently shows). Per the `seqtab`, this is 757 subjects. I'd like the number 757 to appear on the right y-axis (and so on for the other sequences).

Is this possible? I've played around with `axis(side=4, ...)` but never been able to get it to reproduce the spacing of the left y-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. This is a bit of a mess, but the function resets the `par` setting if you include a legend by default, so you need to turn that off. Then you can set the axis a bit more easily, and then we can go back for the legend. This should work with your test data above.

```
#add padding to the right for axis and legend
par("mar"=c(5,4,4,8)+.1)

#plot w/o axis
seqfplot(actcal.seq, pbarw=FALSE, yaxis="pct", tlim=10:1, withlegend=F)

#plot right axis with freqs
axis(4, at = seq(.7, by=1.2, length.out=length(attr(actcal.freq,"freq")$Freq)), 
    labels = rev(attr(actcal.freq,"freq")$Freq), 
    mgp = c(1.5, 0.5, 0), las = 1, tick = FALSE)

#now put the legend on        
legend("right", legend=attr(actcal.seq, "labels"), 
    fill=attr(actcal.seq, "cpal"), 
    inset=-.3, bty="o", xpd=NA, cex=.75)
```

You may need to play a bit with the margins and especially the `inset=` parameter of the `legend` to get it placed correctly. I hope your real data isn't too much different than this because you really have to dig though the function to see how it does the formatting to get things to match up.

[image: TraMineR plot with right y-axis]

Comment: Thank you for your answer MrFlick! I had to alter it slightly to make it work for my data (putting the legend on the bottom, etc.). Also, R gave me the error "Error in seq.default(0.7, by = 1.2, length.out = length(pcts)) : 
  object 'pcts' not found " So I simply specified `length.out = 10` instead.

Comment: @user3684695 Sorry for the error. I don't remember where `pcts` came from anymore, but i've updated the code using the length of the labels so that should always work.